# how to use same Custom domain names for 2 API Mapping in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, path, radix

I have Public REST API in which the Resource per API quota is reached, we don't want to extend the quota as of now so for work-around we create one more API and want to map new api [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utyN2.png)with the existing Custom domain name dev-api-gateway.abc.com . but when we try to map api using GUI getting this error
"Base path already exists for this domain name"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want 2 APIs with the same URL?! which one of them do you expect that message will be forwarded?